# Set the database in a genealogytree

Tags: tcolorbox, pgfkeys, genealogytree

Like in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391176/genealogytree-how-to-populate-node-fields-from-a-csv-file), I'm trying to fill a `genealogytree` with datas from an external source, thanks to the `datatool` package. But I can't figure how to tell genealogytree how to correctly recognize these datas. I probably misunderstands the setting and the use of `pgfkeys`.

The main problem is that `\gtrDBsex` does not execute the right gender `/.style` in the `box` options. If I replace it with a `\def` containing a specific gender, the `/.style` is executed.

Notice that `\gtrPrintName` and `\gtrPrintSex` correctly display their datas.

Where am I wrong? Any help would be kind.

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
%-------------------------------------%
% \def\boy{male}% this one will execute male/.style
\def\someone#1#2{
    \def\nom{#1} % use of control sequences like in the datatool pkg
    \def\sexe{#2}
    \gtrset{database/name={\nom}}%
    \gtrset{database/sex=\sexe}% \gtrif(fe)male doesn't work, but /.style neither.
    % \gtrset{database/sex=male}% even forcing male, /.style doesn't work, considered neuter.
    \gtrPrintName{} \gtrPrintSex{}\\ gender(\gtrDBsex) = \gtrifmale{male}{\gtriffemale{female}{neuter}}%
}
%-------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\genealogytree[
    processing=fit, node size=2.5cm, level size=2cm,
    tcbset={%
        male/.style={colback=blue!20!white,sharp corners},
        female/.style={colback=red!20!white,arc=8pt},%
        neuter/.style={colback=yellow!20!white,arc=8pt}%
    },
    box={\gtrDBsex}% not recognized?
    %box={\boy}% this one executes male/.style
]{%
    parent{
        g{\someone{Gaston}{male}}
        p{\someone{Franck}{male}}
        p{\someone{Lucie}{female}}
    }   
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe compiled]

An alternate problem is that the tests `\gtrifmale` and `\gtriffemale` don't recognize the gender. The `xstring` package does.

Comment: I have never used `genealogytree`, but from looking at its manual, it seems to me the way you are trying to use it doesn't conform to the doc, esp. what you use `\gtrset` for and how you try to declare the sex to gtr. To go from CSV format to `genealogytree`, it seems to me a possible approach would be to first generate an intermediate file like `example.database.graph` in the `genealogytree` manual, then input it as shown e.g. on p. 154 of the manual. To go from CSV to this graph format, many possibilities: for instance, Python if you know it; otherwise, `datatool` can probably do too.

Comment: But why the names and the sex symbols are correctly identified and displayed? I've removed the `datatool` code for the MWE, but the result is the same. I'm diving into the `pgfkeys` documentation, perhaps the datas are stored in a scope that I don't see?

Comment: I assume your `\gtrset{database/name={\nom}}` and `\gtrset{database/sex=\sexe}` commands are manually doing part of the setup that `input`ing a proper `.graph` file would have done. But only part of it; maybe it is already too late to apply the `male` or `female` style to the graph nodes at this point. But these are just impressions/assumptions: I have only browsed through the `genealogytree` manual and tried your example.

Comment: If you have a gedcom file, perhaps you can use my tool: https://github.com/mikkelee/genealogytree-mkgraph

Comment: I'm not familiar with gedcom, but thanks,  I'll study it. From now i'm still with my problem, and not able to give a correct format for a database in the p/c/g braces... I'll oriente my next tests to the "content interpreter" described in the package.

Comment: I guess you want simple input data and expand it into a tree. So maybe that's it:      https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/557508/46023