# genealogytree: How to save database keys in a common key

Tags: tikz-pgf, trees, pgfkeys, key-value, genealogytree

Normally at a genealogytree node I have to say 
`p[]{name=Jane, birth={2-2-1888}{somewhere}}`

How can I create a key, like `persdata=JaneID` which expands to `name=Jane, birth={2-2-1888}{somewhere}`, so that I only have to say: 
`p[]{persdata=JaneID}`

[image]

A not working or correct MWE:

```
\documentclass[landscape,paper=a5]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}
% Works not: 
\pgfkeys{
     persdata/.initial={name=Jane, birth={1-1-1777}{somewhere}},
     persdata/.get=\persdata,
     persdata/.store in=\persdata,
}
\gtrset{database/save/persdata/.get=\persdata}


\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\genealogytree[template=signpost, 
processing=database,
]{
parent{
g{name=first child}
c{name=second child}
c{name=third child}
p[]{persdata=JaneID} % <---------------- Problem here....
p[]{name=works, birth={1-1-1777}{somewhere}}
         }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: have you tried using a `.style` instead? (I have no idea whether this works, I never used `genealogytree` and didn't take a single look, this is just a guess)

Comment: Yes, I tried a style (which would be way easier), but I get the meaning, that he wants a style "[here]", not "{here}"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer provides a new `/gtr/database` key `persdata` that accepts predefined choices like `JaneID`. When `persdata=JaneID` is used, the corresponding key-value list stored in that style is retrieved.

```
\documentclass[landscape,paper=a5]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\begin{document}

\gtrset{
  database/.cd,
  persdata/.is choice,
  persdata/JaneID/.style={name=Jane, birth={1-1-1777}{somewhere}}
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \genealogytree[
    template=signpost, 
    processing=database,
  ]
  {
    parent{
      g{name=first child}
      c{name=second child}
      c{name=third child}
      p[]{persdata=JaneID}
      p[]{name=works, birth={1-1-1777}{somewhere}}
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, very good! Helps me a lot.